# How to match request parameters in wire-mock url?

Tags: java, httprequest, mockserver

I'm trying to create a mock server using wire-mock and I'm facing the following problem: I want to hit an URL like this `/customers?customerId={customerId}&customerNo={customerNo}`.

My question is how can I match the request parameters `customerId` and `customerNo` from the stub of the mock server in Java code.

**EDIT**

After the first response, this is the result:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Here is my stub:

```java
WireMockServer mockServer = new WireMockServer(8079);
mockServer.start();
mockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/api/loan/admin/contracts"))
                .withQueryParam("status", equalTo("ACTIVE"))
                .withQueryParam("cnp", equalTo("1950503410033"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withBody("Welcome to Baeldung!")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the WireMock is hardcoded in UTF-8 format, so when firing requests from browser I didn't send the UTF-8 format to the endpoint. You can't change the WireMock to accept anything instead of UTF-8, but you can fire some UTF-8 requests.

Answer (score 3):

Query parameters can be passed in URL.

In Java:

```
urlEqualTo("/your/url?and=query")
```

Json:

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "/your/url?and=query"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Reference: http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

Example:
Try any of the following:

```
stubFor(any(urlEqualTo("/customers?customerId={your_customer_id}&customerNo={your_customer_no}"))
          .willReturn(aResponse()));


stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/customers"))
          .withQueryParam("customerId", equalTo("your_customer_id"))
          .withQueryParam("customerNo", equalTo("your_customer_no"))
          .willReturn(aResponse()));
```

Comment: Can you help me giving an example in case of my URL? I've read the docs, but I didn't understand very well how to manage with it. Thx.

Comment: I've edited the question. I've do as you suggest, but it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you define your stub?

Comment: Your cnp looks different than the one defined in stub

Comment: Trust me that I've tried with the same cnp query param. It's ok.

Comment: @DinaBogdan I see. You probably need to use 'urlPathEqualTo' instead of  'urlEqualTo' if you're defining parameters separately using 'withQueryParam'

Answer (score 0):

Stubbing with Query Parameters

```
stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("url"))
.withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, matching(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
.withQueryParams(queryParams)
.withRequestBody(equalToJson("request-json-goes-here"))
.willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
.withHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
.withBody("response-json-goes-here")))
```

Where query params is

```
Map<String, StringValuePattern> queryParams = new HashMap<String, StringValuePattern>();
queryParams.put("show_all", equalTo("true"));
```

Verification of the query parameter can be done using `withQueryParam`

```
verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlPathMatching("url"))
.withQueryParam("show_all",equalTo("true")))
```